# error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.web' specified could not be found - .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, dockerfile, .net-5

I can't, for the life of me, figure this out.

This is my HostServer.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Description>HostServer</Description>
    <Copyright></Copyright>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <AssemblyName>HostServer</AssemblyName>
    <PackageId>HostServer</PackageId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.10.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="RestSharp" Version="105.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Annotations" Version="5.0.0-rc4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Interfaces\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\QuicktronWrapper\QuicktronWrapper.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I can see that I have Microsoft.NET.Sdk.web in these folders:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web
```

I am able to build it just fine within Visual Studio. But when I use the 'dotnet build' command as part of creating a docker image, I get the following error:

```
PS D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer> docker build -f D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer\HostServer\Dockerfile -t hostserver .
[+] Building 2.8s (14/18)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 795B                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 382B                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0                                                                                                                                                                       0.8s
 => [internal] load metadata for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [build 1/8] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0@sha256:48922a379d1f54390d5b8655933d3a62877c1fd46d44ab39cb4133fb1d230681                                                                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
 => => transferring context: 4.76MB                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.1s
 => [base 1/2] FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/8] WORKDIR /src                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [build 3/8] COPY [HostServer/HostServer.csproj, HostServer/]                                                                                                                                                                        0.1s
 => [build 4/8] COPY [QuicktronWrapper/QuicktronWrapper.csproj, QuicktronWrapper/]                                                                                                                                                      0.1s
 => [build 5/8] RUN dotnet restore "HostServer/HostServer.csproj"                                                                                                                                                                       0.8s
 => [build 6/8] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.1s
 => [build 7/8] WORKDIR /src/HostServer                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.1s
 => ERROR [build 8/8] RUN dotnet build "HostServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build                                                                                                                                                     0.7s
------
 > [build 8/8] RUN dotnet build "HostServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build:
#16 0.497 Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.9.0+57a23d249 for .NET
#16 0.497 Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
#16 0.497
#16 0.674 /src/HostServer/HostServer.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.web' specified could not be found.
#16 0.676
#16 0.676 Build FAILED.
#16 0.676
#16 0.676 /src/HostServer/HostServer.csproj : error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.web' specified could not be found.
#16 0.676     0 Warning(s)
#16 0.676     1 Error(s)
#16 0.676
#16 0.676 Time Elapsed 00:00:00.10
```

Here is the output after running 'dotnet --info':

```
PS D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer> dotnet --info
.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.201
 Commit:    a09bd5c86c

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.201\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.4
  Commit:  f27d337295

.NET SDKs installed:
  3.0.103 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  3.1.407 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.102 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  5.0.201 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
  Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
PS D:\Repo\HostServer-v2\HostServer>
```

Just for additional information, here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["HostServer/HostServer.csproj", "HostServer/"]
COPY ["QuicktronWrapper/QuicktronWrapper.csproj", "QuicktronWrapper/"]
RUN dotnet restore "HostServer/HostServer.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/HostServer"
RUN dotnet build "HostServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "HostServer.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "HostServer.dll"]
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try to use a capital `W` in `Sdk.web` name, is it just a typo?

Comment: I did, I replaced 'w' with 'W'. Same error, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error for older `ASP.NET Core 3.1` projects, after installing .NET SDK 6. The issue was resolved after adding the `global.json` file, specifying the SDK version 3.1.

Try adding a `global.json` file to the root of the project folder with the following code:

`{  "SDK": { "version": "5.0.201" } }`

more details [The SDK 'name' specified could not be found](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/errors/msb4236?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(MSBuild.CouldNotResolveSdk)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2019)